# While Loop SQL with NULL Condition

Tags: sql-server, while-loop

I will simplify this, in the hope someone can help :)

```
Table A 
ID  ItemID
1   12
2   13
3   14
4   15
5   16
6   17
11  19

Table B 
BID ItemID
8   10
7   11
6   12
9   13
10  14
11  17
```

Joining A.ItemID to B.ItemID to get the BID
Once I get the BID, I need to join this back to the A.ID to get the relevant A.ItemID to join this back to B.BID to get the next B.ItemID and so on untill the BID is NULL

So for example Table A ID 1 (ItemID 12) will link to B.ItemID 12 to retrieve the BID 6, This will link back to Table A ID 6 to get ItemID 17, this will link to Table B ItemID 17 to get BID 11 to link back to Table A on ID 11 to get ItemID 19 and so on until BID is NULL

This could go 10-15 levels deep, so a nested select is not dynamic enough, so I need to achieve this in a While Loop

Any ideas please??

Comment: It would help people to help you if you were to show the schema for the important parts of the BOM and BOMVERSION tables.

Comment: Can you edit your post with the WHILE loop you attempted, and what error you got from it?

Comment: @Charlie1983 Can you edit your question (use the 'edit' link underneath the tags at the bottom of the question) and put the WHILE loop in the question - it's completely unreadable as a comment.

Comment: You could probably also do this, much more efficiently, with a recursive CTE.

Comment: HoneyBadger how do I use a With statement to do this??

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have the time to write a working query for you atm. If you search google for recursive CTE you'll probably find loads of examples and tutorials which will help you.

Comment: any ideas guys, I really stuck with this :(

Answer (score 1):

Try if this works:

Creating your schema:

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
        ID  INT
    ,   ItemID INT
)


CREATE TABLE B
(
        BID INT
    ,   ItemID INT
)

INSERT INTO A (ID, ItemID)
VALUES  (1, 12)
,       (2, 13)
,       (3, 14)
,       (4, 15)
,       (5, 16)
,       (6, 17)
,       (11, 19)


INSERT INTO B (BID, ItemID)
VALUES  (8, 10)
,       (7, 11)
,       (6, 12)
,       (9, 13)
,       (10, 14)
,       (11, 17)
```

Recursive CTE and selection:

```
WITH Rcte AS
(
        SELECT      A.ID ID
        ,           A.ID ID_A
        ,           A.ItemID ItemID_A
        ,           B.BID BID_B
        ,           B.ItemID ItemID_B
        ,           1 Nr
        FROM        A
        JOIN        B
                ON  B.ItemID = A.ItemID

        UNION ALL

        SELECT      Rcte.ID
        ,           B.BID ID_A
        ,           A.ItemID ItemID_A
        ,           B.BID ID_B
        ,           B.ItemID ItemID_B       
        ,           Rcte.Nr + 1
        FROM        rCTE
        JOIN        B
                ON  B.ItemID = Rcte.ItemID_A
        JOIN        A
                ON  A.ID = B.BID
        WHERE       B.BID IS NOT NULL
)


SELECT      SOL.ID
,           SOL.ItemID
FROM        (
                SELECT      ID_A ID
                ,           ItemID_A ItemID
                ,           A.ID CTE_ID
                FROM        Rcte A

                UNION

                SELECT      BID_B
                ,           ItemID_B
                ,           B.ID    
                FROM        Rcte B
            ) SOL
WHERE       SOL.CTE_ID = 1
```

Results:

```
ID  ItemID
1   12
6   12
6   17
11  17
11  19
```